# Mac installers with pkgbuild: Do not execute preinstall and postinstall script in case of a downgrade

Tags: macos, installation, downgrade, pkgbuild, post-install

I made a package with pkgbuild.  In info.plist, BundleIsVersionChecked is set to true.  My package contains a preinstall and postinstall script in the scripts folder.

A downgrade of my application bundle is indeed prevented.  But the preinstall and postinstall script is always run, even if the application bundle is not installed.

How can I tell pkgbuild not to execute the preinstall and postinstall script when a downgrade is happening?

Comment: Seems like this is kinda buggy. I'm noticing that the installer runs, does the pre/post install and reports "Installation Succeeded" but the install was actually prevented. I'm going to file a bug with Apple.